# What is the geometric/algebraic representation of a (partial) differential relation?

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, homotopy-theory, h-principle

My first idea is a kind of equation that may be an inequality too(?) such as:

$$ F(x,u(x),\partial u(x), \partial^2u(x),...)\leq 0 $$

In [Gromov's book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540121770) he generalizes PDEs into partial differential relations. But what exactly is the meaning of these?

In [this summary](https://www.ihes.fr/%7Egromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/248.pdf) of it he sets them up this way:

> Let $p:X\to V $ be a smooth fibration, and let $X^{(r)}$ be the space or $r$-jets of smooth sections of $p$. A section $\phi$ of the bundle $X^{(r)} \to V$ is called *holonomic* if it is the $r$-jet of a section of $p$. A **differential relation** $ \mathcal{R} $ of order $r$ imposed on sections of $p$ is a subset $\mathcal{R} \subset X^{(r)}$. A section $f$ of $p$ is a *solution* of $\mathcal{R}$ if the $r$-jet of $f$ takes values in $\mathcal{R}$.

I can't really do much with this, this definition feels really abstract to me.

In [these lecture papers](http://math.northwestern.edu/%7Ejnkf/classes/hprin/1overview.pdf) the author defines PDRs the following way:

> Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold. Let $E$ be a smooth fibration over $M$, $E \to M$. The space of $k$-jets of the bundle $E$, $J_kE$, is the sections of a bundle $E^{(k)}$ over $M$ whose fiber $J_kE\vert_x$ at a point $x \in M$ is the space of smooth sections of $E$ in a neighborhood of $x$ modulo the equivalence relation that $f \sim g$ if they agree to order k in a neighborhood of $x$ (i.e., if the first $k$ derivatives of $f-g$ vanish when restricted to some arbitrarily small $\mathbb{R}^n \cong U \subset M$ containing $x$). Note that there is a canonical map $j^{(k)}: \Gamma(E)\to J_kE$ from sections of $E$ to $k$-jets of sections of $E$.

> **Defintion 2.1.** A differential relation $\mathcal{R}$ of order $k$ is a subspace of $E^{(k)}$. The space of (holonomic) solutions Sol$_{\mathcal{R}}$ of $\mathcal{R}$ is the image $\Gamma(E)$ in $\Gamma(\mathcal{R})$, i.e., the sections of $\mathcal{R}$ which are $k$-jets of actual section of $E$.

These are quite similar definitions, still i find myself wondering what exactly i am reading.

**What is the geometric(visual)/algebraic representation of this? How could i explain this in simpler terms?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [BULLETIN OF THE
AMERICAN MATHEMATICAL SOCIETY
Volume 49, Number 3, July 2012, Pages 447–453 - SELECTED MATHEMATICAL REVIEWS](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2012-49-03/S0273-0979-2012-01378-2/S0273-0979-2012-01378-2.pdf)

> ...partial differential relations ... are, for the most part,
> under-determined (or, at least, behave like those) and their solutions
> are rather dense in spaces of functions. We solve and classify
> solutions of these equations by means of direct (and not so direct)
> geometric constructions. [These] alluded to above are usually either
> equations or inequalities.

Classical PDEs of order $n$ look like this: $$ F(x,u(x),\partial u(x), \partial^2u(x),...,\partial^nu(x))= 0 $$

And as their domain is in a $n-1$ dimensional *hypersurface*, their solution is too.

A PDR on the other hand is way more under-determined and covers the entire
$n$-*hypervolume* for

$$ F(x,u(x),\partial u(x), \partial^2u(x),...\partial^nu(x))\leq 0 $$

In the example it can take up any negative point on the $x$-axis probably. And this has way more solutions too. This is what the author meant i think by "dense in spaces of solutions".